# How to change url param to object without changing value type?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, object, integer

I am trying to change a url param to object?

```
const url = key=hhdfghh&num=123
const params = Object.fromEntries(new URLSearchParams(url));
console.log(params);
params.num = '123'
```

But i want it to be 123 type int

Comment: Integers do not retain their written form, that is, `000`, `0x00`, `0b00` etc will be represented as `0` no matter what. If you need a literal sequence of characters, you need a string, not an int.

Comment: JavaScript does not store numbers with formatting If you log your initial object, you'd see it's just `0` not `0000`. You can also try `console.log(0000)`. If you want a formatted number, use a string.

Comment: The only way to preserve unnecessary leading zeros is to store it as a string.

Comment: No, `object.integer` is `0`, not `"0000"`. `0000` is not a valid literal in strict mode; if you’re not using [strict mode](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), switch to [modules](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) now, please. If you want to have something with four digits, use a string instead.

Comment: Please don’t change the entire question. A URL is a string; there are no types. If you want to _interpret_ something as a number, you have to _convert_ it to a number using `Number(params.num)`. Note that `Number("0000")` will still be `0`; if you want leading zeros, then you don’t want a Number.